# Monodromy action on the fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two varieties over $\mathbb C$, and $f:X\to Y$ is a proper smooth morphism. Fix any $y\in Y$, and denote $X_y$ the fiber over $y$. Can we get an action of $\pi_1(Y,y)$ on $X_y$? Maybe there needs some kind of "parallel transport"?

Comment: Did you mean Mo**no**dromy?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes,, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Usually not (actually, many varieties have trivial automorphisms groups).

Comment: The monodromy action is associated to a 'covering-space-like object'. Examples include the action of $\pi_1(Y)$ on the fibers of $f\colon X\to Y$ when $f$ is a *covering map*, or the action of $\pi_1(Y)$ on $\mathscr{L}_y$ for a local system $\mathscr{L}$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes, but for example if we let $X$ be the tangent bundle of $Y$, we can get an action of $\pi_1(Y,y)$ on $T_y$ by using parallel transport right? So I wonder if the case I mentioned is also true.

Comment: @Sasha Sorry I didn't get the point. Trivial automorphism groups doesn't affect the question.

Comment: @Richard: If a variety has no automorphisms any group action on it is trivial, right?